# Associating values to rows based on random number

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of 100 records and I am trying to associate a random number to each record. At the moment, I have this:

```
df['RAND'] = [random.uniform(0,1) for k in df.index]
```

which seems to work. I then want to associate an 'L' value to each record based on where this random number falls in a given interval. For instance,

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if 0.89 <= df['RAND'] <= 1:
        i = 'L0'
    elif 0.1 <= df['RAND'] < 0.89:
        i = 'L1'
```

And so on. I am having trouble executing this last part because I am unsure how to associate an 'L' value to each specific record.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `if 0.89 <= df['RAND'][i]<= 1:` `df['RAND'][i]='L0'` and so on

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks for your comment. I think this is what I was trying to do but I now keep getting the error ''<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str''.

Comment: Try `float(df['RAND'][i])` although I don't see what's `str` here

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`np.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) specifying `size` argument, which is faster than looping*

```
df['RAND'] = np.random.uniform(0,1, size=df.index.size)
```

To assign the `L`s, you can use `np.select` specifying the conditions and the values

```
conditions = [df.RAND >=0.89, (df.RAND < 0.89) & (df.RAND >= 0.1), df.RAND < 0.1]
choices = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2']

df['L'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

These approaches are better than looping through the data frame. If you loop through the data frame, you lose all the power that the `pandas` library brings to the table ;)

---

*

```
%timeit [random.uniform(0,1) for k in range(10000)]
3.41 ms ± 65.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.random.uniform(0,1, size=10000)
113 µs ± 2.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A final thing, if I wanted to select other information for a record given its L value, would I be able to do this? For instance, something like `if choices = 'LF0'` then select its value from the 'percentage' column, and so on.

Comment: @EarlofMar Glad I could help! Not sure I understand your question, but I guess you want something like `df.loc[df['L'] == 'L0', 'RAND']` ?

Comment: Yes sort of. I essentially want to say, given the L value that has been assigned to the record, pull its value from the 'percentage' column and store it (maybe in a matrix or something). I want to do this because a record's 'percentage' value changes according to the L value assigned to the record. Iterating 1000 times would hence mean a different 'L' value for the same record for different iterations.

Comment: @EarlofMar Sorry but I don't understand what you need.. whats wrong with `df.loc[df['L'] == 'L0', 'RAND'].values`?